# Why is my char array condition not working

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, char, conditional-statements

I'm doing an assignment for my intro to cis. one of the conditions was that if at anytime the name variable matched the EOFNAME variable that the program would quit. I made a char array so i could store a name and if instead of putting your name you put quit it would exit. I made the program and compiled it ran without issue except when you put in Quit it doesn't it just continues and uses that as the name variable

```cpp
char name[10];
char EOFNAME[10] = "Quit";

void housekeeping()
{
    do{ cout << "Enter first name or " << EOFNAME << " to quit this session" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cin.get();
    if ( name != EOFNAME)
    {
        mainloop();
    }
    else if(name == EOFNAME)
    {
       break;
    }

   }while(name != EOFNAME);
}
```

Comment: This `name == EOFNAME` won't do what you are expecting.

Comment: sadly you cannot compare arrays like that. The compiler thinks you are trying to compare their addresses, not their contents. May I recommend using `std:: string` instead of arrays? If `std::array` is not permitted, you will need to use `strcmp` or perform a character by character comparison with a loop of your own making.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because to compare `char` arrays you need `strcmp` function, e.g. `strcmp(name, EOFNAME)!=0`. Your `name!=EOFNAME` just compares pointers to the beginning of the arrays, and the pointers are never equal.

But in more idiomatic C++, you can declare your variables `std::string` instead of `char [10]`. Then you can use `name!=EOFNAME` condition.